# Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation: Printing out array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, string, swap

I have a function, which prints out an array of strings. The second function is supposed to print the reversed list but for some reason a new tab called xmemory pops up and I get the message: **"Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. this->_Myproxy was 0xCCCCCCCC."** After hours of searching for this online, I finally decided to see if someone here could help me.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void display(string array[5]);
void displayReverse(string array[5]);

int main()
{
    string fruit[5] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry"};
    display(fruit);
    displayReverse(fruit);
    return 0;
}

void display(string array[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
}

void displayReverse(string array[5])
{
    swap(array[1], array[5]);
    swap(array[2], array[4]);
    swap(array[4], array[5]);

    cout << array[1] << endl << array[2] << endl << array[3] << endl << array[4] << endl << array[5] << endl;
}
```

Comment: valid indices are  `0` till `size-1`. `array[5]` is out-of-bounds and invokes undefinded behavior.

Comment: fwiw if you use `std::array` and reverse iterators you can write the whole code without mentioning a single index explicitly. or `std::reverse` if you not only want to print reversed, but actually reverse the array

Comment: Some one asked the same question last evening. If you have c++20 this can help: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view)

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working now!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Array index start from 0. It won't start from 1. So if you have array with 5 elements, you can access the first element by array[0]. array[1] represents second element. Your displayReverse() is trying to access 6th element in the array which doesn't exist.

Below is the code with some modifications.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void display(string array[], int size);
void displayReverse(string array[]);

int main()
{
    string fruit[5] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry"};
    display(fruit, 5);
    displayReverse(fruit);
    return 0;
}

void display(string array[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
}

void displayReverse(string array[])
{
    swap(array[0], array[4]);
    //swap(array[2], array[3]);
    swap(array[1], array[3]);

    cout << array[0] << endl << array[1] << endl << array[2] << endl << array[3] << endl << array[4] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void display(string array[5]);
void displayReverse(string array[5]);

int main()
{
    string fruit[5] = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Kiwi", "Cherry"};
    display(fruit);
    displayReverse(fruit);
    return 0;
}

void display(string array[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }
}

void displayReverse(string array[5])
{
        for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i-=1)
    {
        cout << array[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Use loops instead of swaps. It is really better idea.